# SSL handshake with SNI extension enabled - certificate selection on server

Tags: ssl, handshake, sni

During the SSL handshake, when the SNI extension is enabled in the client the server is not selecting and presenting the desired certificate back to the client.

I have a certificate chain that I've imported to the JVM's keystore on the server.

server certificate issued by an internal intermediate issuing CA.

Subject: CN=myserver.example.com

intermediate certificate issued by internal root CA.

```
        X509v3 Key Usage:
            Digital Signature, Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
        X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
            CA:TRUE
```

self signed root CA certificate.

```
    X509v3 extensions:
        X509v3 Key Usage:
            Digital Signature, Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
        X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
            CA:TRUE
```

I used "openssl s_client" to test.

I used the following command to test with Server Name Indication (SNI) TLS extension **disabled** and the certificate chain in the keystore is selected and presented by the server in the SSL handshake. That's what I expected.

openssl s_client -connect myserver.example.com:port

I used the following command to test with the Server Name Indication (SNI) TLS extension **enabled** and a different (default?) certificate was selected and presented by the server in the SSL handshake. This certificate is not in the keystore. I did not expect this.

openssl s_client -connect myserver.example.com:port -servername myserver.example.com

I'm trying to figure out why the server is not selecting my certificate chain that's in the keystore, and instead is selecting the "other" (default?) certificate when the SNI extension is enabled. Any help would be appreciated.

I don't know how certificate selection works on the server during the SSL handshake process.

Comment: What software is the server? Where does he find the certificate sent in the second case?

Comment: It's a RHEL server running third party software (SnapLogic). jre1.8.0_45 comes bundled with their software. I don't know where the certificate in the second case is coming from. It's not in the keystore.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know how certificate selection works on the server during the SSL handshake process.

If the client doesn't send the SNI, the server *should* answer with the default certificate (but some servers are not configured with any default, and the handshake fails). If the client sends the SNI, the server should choose the appropriate certificate. Your problem looks strange because it doesn't look like either possibilities.
Try upgrading your JVM (OpenJDK ? Oracle ?) to the latest, as there were many changes since your version, for example [Support TLS Server Name Indication (SNI) Extension in JSSE Server](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7068321).

Comment: Thank you. I will look into this.